# How can i place special characters in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

In php I can do this to place a back slash inside an array

```
$symbols = array(".","\\\\");
```

What is the best method of doing this in javascript with backslash, colon, and semicolon?

Comment: Inside a `string` value, correct? PHP and JavaScript share the same rules for backslash-escaped characters in strings which they inherited from C.

Comment: yes inside of an array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Array_literals) delimited by square brackets:

```js
var symbols = [".","\\", ":", ";"];
console.log(symbols);
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for a more thorough explanation of arrays and their methods.

Answer (score 1):

you need to scape backslash (backslash is the escape keyword). If you need to push an item to the array use the push() method.

```js
let arr = ['\\', ':'];
arr.push(';');

console.log(arr);   //Outputs ["\", ":", ";"]
```